# Proper name for a new method

Tags: publications, thesis, terminology, methodology

We developed a new method to calculate a characteristic value from measurement data. In my thesis I call the existing method 'Original Method'. However, I am not sure how to name our new method. 'Current Method'? 'Present Method'?

Is there an established standard for this?

Comment: "Proposed"? "Our"? Perhaps asking at ELU might also make some headway.

Comment: I suspect the answer is no, but if you tell us the field you're working in then it might increase the chances of getting an answer.

Comment: 'Algorithm 1.1' is also a good choice --- using the label you put next to the pseudocode or explicit formulation of the method. There is no explicit formulation you can refer to? Well, fix that. :)

Comment: Thanks everyone for your contributions. I went with  @Federico's suggestion and used the terms "Method 1" and "Method 2".

Answer (score 3):

The following terms may help.

- Proposed method
- Suggested method
- Our technique
- Algorithm devised
- Intended design
- New procedure

It's not an exhaustive list, but are considered acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

If the new method derives directly from an older method X, "Improved X method" is a reasonable option. Otherwise, choose a descriptive name which reflects your new contribution.

Comment: Nice. You could also replace *improved* with *enhanced*. If you are combining one method to an existing one, you could use the word *augmented*.